# polyglossia in TeX Live 2017: Bug for `latesthyphen`?

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, polyglossia

I have upgraded to TeX Live 2017 and noticed that the hyphenation behavior has changed compared to 2016. More explicitly, while hyphenation worked previously, there was no hyphenation anymore for the very same source files.

I traced the issue to the `polyglossia` option `latesthyphen` for German.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[latesthyphen=true]{german}

\begin{document}
Normaler Text. Normaler Text. Normaler Text. Normaler Text. Normaler Text. Normaler Text. Normaler Text.

Telekommunikationsüberwachung geht Unternehmenssteuerfortentwicklungsgesetz

\end{document}
```

For `latesthyphen=true` one gets
[image]

For `latesthyphen=false` one gets
[image]

Is this potentially a bug? I couldn't find any documentation that stated a deliberate change in polyglossia...

EDIT –– This is the log file:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)  (format=lualatex 2017.9.27)  9 OCT 2017 17:02
restricted system commands enabled.
**Sandbox.tex
(./Sandbox.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2017/01/29 2.80001 OpenType layout system.
Lua module: lualibs 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2017-02-01 2.5 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended co
llection.(using write cache: /Users/florian/Library/texlive/2017basic/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic)(using read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-var/l
uatex-cache/generic /Users/florian/Library/texlive/2017basic/texmf-var/luatex-ca
che/generic)
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /Users/florian/Library/texlive/2017b
asic/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2017-02-11.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/
fontloader-2017-02-11.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 3
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.027”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 4
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /Users/florian/Library/texlive/2017b
asic/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.104 seconds
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /Users/florian/Library/texlive
/2017basic/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc(load luc: /
Users/florian/Library/texlive/2017basic/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/lmroman10-regular.luc))
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
Package: polyglossia 2015/03/25 v1.42.4 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and Lua
LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count87
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty
Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (code)
\ucharcat@table=\catcodetable5
\c_max_int=\count89
\l_tmpa_int=\count90
\l_tmpb_int=\count91
\g_tmpa_int=\count92
\g_tmpb_int=\count93
\g__intarray_font_int=\count94
\g__prg_map_int=\count95
\c_log_iow=\count96
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count97
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count98
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count99
\l__iow_indent_int=\count100
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count101
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_rand_size_int=\count111
\c__fp_rand_four_int=\count112
\c__fp_rand_eight_int=\count113
\l__sort_length_int=\count114
\l__sort_min_int=\count115
\l__sort_top_int=\count116
\l__sort_max_int=\count117
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count118
\l__sort_block_int=\count119
\l__sort_begin_int=\count120
\l__sort_end_int=\count121
\l__sort_A_int=\count122
\l__sort_B_int=\count123
\l__sort_C_int=\count124
\l__tl_build_start_index_int=\count125
\l__tl_build_index_int=\count126
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count127
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count128
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count129
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count130
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count131
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count132
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count133
\l__regex_balance_int=\count134
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count135
\l__regex_mode_int=\count136
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count137
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count138
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count139
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count140
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count141
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count142
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count143
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count144
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count145
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count146
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count147
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count148
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count149
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count150
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count151
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count152
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count153
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count154
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count155
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count156
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count157
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count158
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count159
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count160
\l__regex_step_int=\count161
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count162
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count163
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count164
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count165
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count166
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count167
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count168
\g__debug_trace_regex_int=\count169
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen109
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen123
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def
File: l3pdfmode.def 2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count170
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box41
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2017/09/18 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count171
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count172
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count173
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count174
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count175
)
Package: fontspec 2017/09/22 v2.6e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
Lua module: fontspec 2017/09/27 2.6e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
Package: fontspec-luatex 2017/09/22 v2.6e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count176
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def
File: tuenc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 482.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 486.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 490.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 494.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 498.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 502.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 506.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 510.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setromanfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 514.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 518.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 522.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 526.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 530.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeature with sig. 'm' on line 534.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 538.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 542.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 546.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newICUfeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 550.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 554.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 558.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 562.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 566.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 570.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \IfFontFeatureActiveTF with sig. 'mmm' on line 574.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCommand with sig. 'mO{}m' on line 3284.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingAccent with sig. 'mm' on line 3290.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingSymbol with sig. 'mm' on line 3296.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingComposite with sig. 'mmm' on line 3302.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCompositeCommand with sig. 'mmm' on line 3308.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareUnicodeEncoding with sig. 'mm' on line 3333.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareSymbol with sig. 'm' on line 3339.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareComposite with sig. 'mm' on line 3347.
.................................................

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 3525.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 3530.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 3535.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 3540.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 3570.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 3595.
(load luc: /Users/florian/Library/texlive/2017basic/texmf-var/luatex-cache/gener
ic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-bold.luc)(load luc: /Users/florian/Library/texlive/2017ba
sic/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-italic.luc)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 3646.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 3741.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 3745.
.................................................
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
Package: luatexbase 2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 

(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty
Package: ctablestack 2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
\@catcodetablestackcnt=\count184
)
\CatcodeTableOther=\catcodetable6
\CatcodeTableExpl=\catcodetable7
)
luatex-hyphen: using data file: /usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-var/tex/gener
ic/config/language.dat.lua
Lua module: polyglossia 2013/05/11 1.3 Polyglossia)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-german.ldf
File: gloss-german.ldf polyglossia: module for german
hyph-de-1901.pat.txt
Language german was not yet loaded; created with id 4
Language german already loaded; id is 4
hyph-de-1996.pat.txt
Language ngerman was not yet loaded; created with id 8
Language ngerman already loaded; id is 8
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/babelsh.def
File: babelsh.def 2013/04/30 Babel common definitions for shorthands
Taken verbatim from babel.def (2013/04/15 v3.9e)
)
Package polyglossia Info: Making " an active character on input line 79.
)
Package polyglossia Info: Default language is german.

(./Sandbox.aux
luatex-hyphen: loading patterns and exceptions for: german (\language4)
luatex-hyphen: info: no hyphenation exceptions for this language
Language ngerman already loaded; id is 8)
\openout1 = Sandbox.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/bx/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmr/bx/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/bx/n on input line 5.

Language ngerman-x-latest not found in language.dat.lua
Language ngerman-x-latest not found in language.dat.lua
Overfull \hbox (26.77pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--9
[]\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Telekommunikationsüberwachung geht Unternehmenssteuerfortentw
icklungsgesetz 
[]

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./Sandbox.aux
luatex-hyphen: loading patterns and exceptions for: german (\language4)
luatex-hyphen: info: no hyphenation exceptions for this language
Language ngerman-x-latest not found in language.dat.lua))

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
10804 strings out of 494481
125171,383344 words of node,token memory allocated
386 words of node memory still in use:
3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 4 attribute, 49 glue_spec, 4 attribute_list
, 1 write nodes
avail lists: 1:1,2:23,3:8,4:2,5:40,6:167,7:32,8:1,9:9,10:1
14855 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
25 fonts using 5677367 bytes
41i,4n,35p,848b,229s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
</usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regu
lar.otf>
Output written on Sandbox.pdf (1 page, 5293 bytes).

PDF statistics: 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

A line of interest might be:

```
Language ngerman-x-latest not found in language.dat.lua
```

Comment: Well, the docs say it's experimental. And maybe those hyphenation patterns were removed from the "latest" file...

Comment: I get hyphenation with both settings. Can you show your log-file?

Comment: I added the log file in the edit above. `Language ngerman-x-latest not found in language.dat.lua` could be of interest.

Comment: I don't know whether it matters, but I am actually using BasicTeX.

Comment: I get `Language ngerman-x-latest already loaded` and, yes, the problem is most likely BasicTeX. Why not installing the full MacTeX and forget about missing packages?

Comment: I agree one could do that. But the existence of BasicTeX suggests that there are people interested in a more minimalistic approach. While one could argue against it, I think such a technical issue as I am having should rather be ironed out (I am unfortunately not skilled enough to do that myself) than be the reason for not using BasicTeX altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “minimalistic approach” is, in my opinion, doomed to failure and your problems are good examples.

In order to find the packages that support German hyphenation you can try, from a terminal window,

```
tlmgr info dehyph
```

(the hyphenation files have recently been given uniform names). The output on my machine is

```
tlmgr: cannot find package dehyph, searching for other matches:

Packages containing `dehyph' in their title/description:
dehyph-exptl - Experimental hyphenation patterns for the German language
hyphen-german - German hyphenation patterns.

Packages containing files matching `dehyph':
00texlive.image:
    tlpkg/tlpsrc/dehyph-exptl.tlpsrc
dehyph-exptl:
    texmf-dist/doc/generic/dehyph-exptl/CHANGES
    texmf-dist/doc/generic/dehyph-exptl/INSTALL
    texmf-dist/doc/generic/dehyph-exptl/LICENSE
    texmf-dist/doc/generic/dehyph-exptl/README
    texmf-dist/doc/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyph-exptl.bib
    texmf-dist/doc/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyph-exptl.pdf
    texmf-dist/doc/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyph-exptl.tex
    texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyphn-x-2017-03-31.pat
    texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyphn-x-2017-03-31.tex
    texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehypht-x-2017-03-31.pat
    texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehypht-x-2017-03-31.tex
    texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyphts-x-2017-03-31.pat
    texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyphts-x-2017-03-31.tex
hyphen-german:
    texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/dehyphn.tex
    texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/dehypht.tex
    texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/dehyphtex.tex
```

Now you know that the package you need for the experimental German hyphenation patterns is `dehyph-exptl`.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for helping people to help themselves!